# double 2d array malloc for distributed mem programming (MPI)

Tags: c, malloc, mpi

the task is to use MPI in distributed memory to take average of 4 adjacent values in a (size x size) matrix, and the start/end/workload are areas worked out for each process to do the maths, then the edges of those areas are exchanged
(note that top and bottom row are untouched calculation wise, but necessary to do other rows)
this is repeated until a certain precision is met in the overall calculation
I cant seem to figure out what to do with my array creation as it keeps giving me segmentation fault error (11), signal code (128)
any help is appreciated, thank u in advance

this function takes

- size (size of matrix, column in my case)
- workload (the amount of lines each process will do maths)
- start (starting position in the array)
- end (end position in the array

the current inputs are:

- size = 30
- processes = 6
  so the split work for a 30x30 array would be:
- proc rank0 = workload = 5 (start = 1, end = 6)
- proc rank1 = workload = 5 (start = 6, end = 11)
- proc rank2 = workload = 5 (start = 11, end = 16)
- proc rank3 = workload = 5 (start = 16, end = 21)
- proc rank4 = workload = 4 (start = 21, end = 25)
- proc rank5 = workload = 4 (start = 25, end = 29)

```
double** createArray(int size, int workload, int start, int end, int rank){ 
//memory is allocated for the matrix
    double** arr = (double**) malloc(sizeof(double*)*(workload+2));
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    }
    
    //writes the start vlaues into the matrix
    //we need workload and extra edges each
    for (int i=start-1; i<end+1; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<size; j++){
            //the upper and left rows are set to 1
            if (i==0){
                arr[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else if (j==0){
                arr[i][j] = 1;
            }
            //other elements are set to 0 
            else{
                arr[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    if(rank == 0){
        for (int i=start-1; i<end+1; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<end; j++){
                printf("%lf", arr[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    */
    //returns the array 
    return arr;
    }
```

ive tried going over values and variabels many times but with no luck
any help is appreciated, many thanks

Comment: There's no check if the workload is less than the size. If you send in a smaller workload than the size, it'll surely access the allocated memory out of bounds. What input are you giving it when it crashes?

Comment: just updated info on the post, sorry for initial lack of information

Comment: Perhaps it'd be better if you put the driver code in `main` which makes these 6 calls to `createArray`. If I understand it correctly, the first call will be `createArray(30, 5, 1, 6, 5)` - and that will definitely access `arr` out of bounds in `arr[29]` since you've only allocated space for 5+2 `double*`. Why `+2` btw?

Comment: @TedLyngmo the +2 is necessary as the program looks at an elements 4 adjacent values (top bottom left right) and takes the average, and does that for its section (workload x size array), which itself is a subsection of a size x size array split amongst processes.
after all processes are done with its round of maths, the edge values will be exchanged and repeated until the value difference in the maths reaches a precision

Comment: @TedLyngmo, to your suggestion, sorry im quite inexperienced but i wanted to allocate workload + 2 (so accounting for both edges) rows, then in the inner loop allocate for size (columns). is this where ive made a mistake?

Comment: Well, `double** arr = (double**) malloc(sizeof(double*)*(workload+2));` when `workload` is `5` allocates space for 7 `double*`, but you then `for (int i=0; i<size; i++){ arr[i]` and since `size` is 30, it _does_ look very wrong.

Comment: @TedLyngmo would 
```
double** arr = (double**) malloc(sizeof(double*)*(workload+2));
    for (int i=0; i<(workload+2); i++){
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    }
```
be correct?

Comment: I can't say if it's correct, but that does will at least not access `arr` out of bounds, so it will at least not cause the same issue as the current code.

Comment: that solved the first malloc error, thank you very much for the kind help :)

Comment: jagged array are not a good fit for MPI. You need to allocate 2D arrays in contiguous memory, do it manually (e.g. `double *`) or use 2D arrays (e.g. `double[workload+2][size]`)